# Modeling and Displaying Map of NYC: Virus Simulation

Tags: python, matplotlib

So I finished writing the code to display the image of the map of NYC which should look like this

[image]

But with the current code that I have:

```
import random
import string
import math
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

def normpdf(x, mean, sd):
"""
Return the value of the normal distribution 
with the specified mean and standard deviation (sd) at
position x.
You do not have to understand how this function works exactly. 
"""
var = float(sd)**2
denom = (2*math.pi*var)**.5
num = math.exp(-(float(x)-float(mean))**2/(2*var))
return num/denom


recovery_time = 4 # recovery time in time-steps
virality = 0.2    # probability that a neighbor cell is infected in 
              # each time step                                                  

class Cell(object):

    def __init__(self,x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y 
        self.state = "S" # can be "S" (susceptible), "R" (resistant = dead), or 
                     # "I" (infected)

    def infect(self):
    pass

class Map(object):
    cells_list = []

    def __init__(self):
        self.height = 150
        self.width = 150           
        self.cells = {}

    def add_cell(self, cell):
        self.cells_list.append((cell.x, cell.y))
        self.cells_list.append(cell.state)



    def display(self):
        colors = []
        for y in range(150):
            for x in range(150):
                if (x, y) in self.cells:
                    if self.cells[(x,y)] in "S":
                        colors.append((0.0,1.0, 0.0))
                    elif self.cells[(x, y)] in "R":
                        colors.append((0.5, 0.5, 0.5))
                    else:
                        colors.append((1.0, 0.0, 0.0))
                else:
                    colors.append((0.0,0.0,0.0))
        plt.imshow(colors)

def adjacent_cells(self, x,y):
    pass


def read_map(filename):
    m = Map()
    coordinates = open(filename, 'r')
    coordinates_list = coordinates.readlines()
    for l in coordinates_list:
        line = l.strip()
        split_coords = line.split(',')
        c = Cell(split_coords[0], split_coords[1])
        m.add_cell(c)

  # ... Write this function

   return m

 read_map('nyc_map.txt').display()
```

I get this image instead:

[image]

By the way, our map is a 150 x 150 grid; to create the image I have to use a list of a list

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot wrong with your code:

- several indenting errors
- `colors` is a list of 150*150 tuples of length 3, but the input to `imshow` should be an array of size (150,150,3).
- `self.cells[(x,y)] in "S"` checks if the content of `self.cells[(x,y)]` is contained in the string `"S"`, which can only be true if `self.cells[(x,y)] == "S"`. `self.cells` is initialized with `{}` and never set elsewhere so the condition is always false.
- `self.cells[(x,y)]` expects `x` and `y` to be integers, however `Cell(split_coords[0], split_coords[1])` uses strings when creating a cell.

Here is a fixed version with all code removed which is unnecessary for the example:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

class Cell(object):

    def __init__(self,x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.state = "S" # can be "S" (susceptible), "R" (resistant = dead), or
                     # "I" (infected)

class Map(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.cells = {}

    def add_cell(self, cell):
        self.cells[(cell.x, cell.y)] = cell.state

    def display(self):
        colors = np.zeros((150,150,3))
        for y in range(150):
            for x in range(150):
                if (x, y) in self.cells:
                    if self.cells[(x,y)] == "S":
                        colors[x,y,:] = (0.0,1.0, 0.0)
                else:
                    colors[x, y, :] = (0.0,0.0,0.0)

        plt.imshow(colors)
        plt.show()

def read_map(filename):
    m = Map()
    coordinates = open(filename, 'r')
    coordinates_list = coordinates.readlines()
    for l in coordinates_list:
        line = l.strip()
        split_coords = line.split(',')
        c = Cell(int(split_coords[0]), int(split_coords[1]))
        m.add_cell(c)

    # ... Write this function

    return m

read_map('nyc_map.txt').display()
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help me figure out where I went wrong!